# Need Algorithm for grouping nodes into group-aware collections

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for the solution to a similar problem as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630679/dividing-connected-nodes-into-groups-of-three), but now there are some more conditions:

- Nodes are connected to a minimum of K nodes, but no specific maximum
- Nodes will usually not be aware of all other nodes in the cluster, and the number of nodes will usually change over time
- All groups need to have unique group identifiers (GIDs) in the whole cluster.
- A node can be a member of many groups at the same time
- All members are aware of their current GID and aware of all present group GIDs
- The algorithm will be repeated regularly, and in each iteration, a node will NOT be grouped with the EXACT same previous group members again (randomness implied...?)
- Nodes can confirm the authenticity of a given node's membership in a given group using a standard algorithm*
- (Added) There should be no centralized control. Any node in the system should be able to run the algorithm at the given time period, but all nodes should be able to come to the same common understanding

So, a good solution will be something like:

- A node N is in a group with a Node ID of NID1, and a Group ID of GID1. Also, any other node M in a random group GIDm can confirm authenticity of N being in the Group having the group ID of GID1
- Either node N or M knows all group IDs GID1, GID2...GIDn in the cluster
- (Added) when the algorithm is executed again, the node should have mostly completely different members in it's new group(s), and if possible, all new members should be new

That's pretty much it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the use of  nodes coordinator system like zookeeper is allowed ?

Comment: No, the nodes should be able to coordinate among themselves and come to a common understanding. The algorithm should be able to run from any node and come to the same conclusion no matter what. Let me edit to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification